# Find unique values from records that contain duplicate values in a different field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to return all value of the_id that have been received within the past 8 days and there is at least 1 duplicated name. This should return 1,5.

[image: MYTABLE]

```
SELECT the_id, count(*) c FROM "MYTABLE" WHERE "received" < date('now','-8 days') GROUP BY the_name HAVING c > 1;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It is grouping by name and returning 1 of the_id, not 2 of them

Comment: I need the values of 1 and 5 returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
SELECT a.the_id
FROM   "MYTABLE" A, "MYTABLE" B
WHERE  (a.the_name = b.the_name)
       AND 
       (a."received" < date('now','-8 days') 
        AND b."received" < date('now','-8 days')
       )
Group by a.the_id 
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Closer, but this doesn't work with the dates correctly. If 1 received is within 8 days and the other isn't, it is still returning 1 the_id. It should only return a value if more than 1 is received within the 8 days

Comment: Ok. I fixed it by adding      and b."received" < date('now','-8 days')

Comment: Update your answer (unless I am missing something) and I will accept.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be an AND?